# Passing Array of Object via an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a simple prototype form, which consists of two components (search and result) and a service (query).

To summarise briefly before I get into detail, I would like an action on the search component to update data in the results pane.

In my prototype posted below this works with a simple String.  I can type a string into an input box and every time I click submit this calls the service setting the value (calling service.setData), the results component observes that its changed and updated the label accordingly.  I've tried doing the same with an array of an object, but whatever I try it refuses to update in real time.  It will work on the initial load though.  I have added the service into the providers.

search.component.html - as this is a simple test, this has two buttons which call slightly different methods.

```
Set data to:

<input [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" placeholder="Enter data here"/>

<button (click)="getSearchResults1(searchTerm); searchTerm=''">Submit 1</button>
<button (click)="getSearchResults2(searchTerm); searchTerm=''">Submit 2</button>
```

search.component.ts

```
  constructor(private queryService: QueryService) {}

  getSearchResults1(searchTerm: string):void {    
    this.queryService.setAccountData1();
    this.queryService.setData(searchTerm);
  }

  getSearchResults2(searchTerm: string):void {
    this.queryService.setAccountData2();
    this.queryService.setData(searchTerm);
  }

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.queryService.setAccountData3();
  }
```

query.service.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private data: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  getData(): Observable<string> {
    return this.data;
  }

  setData(d: string): void {
    this.data.next(d);
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////

  private accountData: Observable<Account[]> = new Observable(null);

  private accountUrl = 'assets/accounts.json';
  private accountUrl2 = 'assets/accounts2.json';
  private accountUrl3 = 'assets/accounts3.json';

  getAccountData(): Observable<Account[]> {
    return this.accountData;
  }

  setAccountData1(): void {
    this.accountData = this.http.get<Account[]>(this.accountUrl)
  }
  setAccountData2(): void {
    this.accountData = this.http.get<Account[]>(this.accountUrl2)
  }
  setAccountData3(): void {
    this.accountData = this.http.get<Account[]>(this.accountUrl3)
  }
```

results.component.html - the string version at the top works fine, the two slightly different versions of trying to do this with an array of an object both fail.

```
The new value is: <br />

<div>{{data|async}}</div>

<br /><hr /><br />

Array is: <br />

<ul class="search-result">
    <li *ngFor="let account of accountData|async" >

        {{account.firstName}}

    </li>
  </ul> 

  <ul class="search-result">
    <li *ngFor="let account2 of accountData2" >

        {{account2.firstName}}

    </li>
  </ul>
```

results.component.ts

```
  constructor(private queryService: QueryService) {}

  data: Observable<string>;    
  accountData: Observable<Account[]>;    
  accountData2: Account[];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.data = this.queryService.getData();

    this.accountData = this.queryService.getAccountData();

    this.queryService.getAccountData().subscribe(a => this.accountData2 = a);

  }
```

1) When the page first loads, the Onit of the search components loads the setAccountData3, which displays a list of firstnames in the third dataset of accounts.

2) I type in a string value into the input box on the search component and click either button, the string value will be outputted on the results component in real time.

3) The array of object doesn't update on either button.  Both submit buttons use a slightly different method of updating the array.  I can tell from outputting to the console that the array value is being set, but the result component does not see this action like it does with almost the same coding on the string version.

Edit.................
To confirm this is a simple prototype to test out the principles that I will need in later projects.  I know in this particular instance I could simplify the solution to achieve the results I want.  I especially would like a component to 'listen' for changes in a service and act upon it, this works for strings easily enough but i can't get it working for an array of objects.

Comment: what happens if you would import ChangeDetectorRef and force cdr.detectChanges()? if the code works with “string” but does not with an Array - it sort of hints Angular does not see array changing. Try triage this with cdr if it works then you would need to ensure array updates are implemented differently

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for the HTML, I am not sure why you divide 2 component Search and Result. You can combine both of them. For Angular, when you have 2 HTML components (take yours as example), you will have 2 seperate component.ts, component.spec.ts, etc. and link them will be a little bit of challenging. I would suggest them to be combined together. Secondly, because you are using the [(ngModel)], you don't have to pass the property "searchTerm" into a method. Here is my suggested solution

> .component.html

```
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" placeholder="Enter data here"/>

    <button (click)="getSearchResults1()>Submit 1</button>
    <button (click)="getSearchResults2()>Submit 2</button>



 <-- YOUR RESULT WILL SHOWED HERE -->
   The new value is: <br />

    <div>{{data|async}}</div>

    <br /><hr /><br />

    Array is: <br />

    <ul class="search-result">
        <li *ngFor="let account of searchTerm | async" >

            {{account.firstName}}

        </li>
      </ul> 

      <ul class="search-result">
        <li *ngFor="let account2 of searchTerm " >

            {{account2.firstName}}

        </li>
      </ul>
```

> From that, your component.ts would be like this

```
searchTerm: any;
constructor(private queryService: QueryService) {}

ngOnInit() {  
  this.getSearchResults3();
}

  getSearchResults1()  {    
    this.queryService.setAccountData1()
      .subcribe(data => {
         this.searchTerm = data;
      }
  }

  getSearchResults2()  {
    this.queryService.setAccountData2()
      .subcribe(data => {
         this.searchTerm = data;
      }
  }

  getSearchResults3()  {
    this.queryService.setAccountData3()
        .subcribe(data => {
          this.searchTerm = data;
        }
 }
```

> query.service.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private accountUrl = 'assets/accounts.json';
  private accountUrl2 = 'assets/accounts2.json';
  private accountUrl3 = 'assets/accounts3.json';

  setAccountData1(): Observable<Account>{
    return this.http.get<Account>(this.accountUrl)
  }
  setAccountData2(): Observable<Account>{
    return this.http.get<Account>(this.accountUrl2)
  }
  setAccountData3(): Observable<Account>{
    return this.http.get<Account>(this.accountUrl3)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  In this prototype I've kept it simple and it could be simplified.  Its mainly about testing the principle so when I want to use it for a more complicated project later on I can do.

Comment: I see. Some of your work I see they were not used correctly so I made adjustments. Did it work for you?
[edited] I can answer regarding the observable if you may need

Comment: Yes when I tried the above it did work for the simple example above.  In an upcoming project I will need to have a service which is called and subscribed to by multiple components, I don't think your example will allow me to do that though.